# How to convert a floating point value greater than Int.max to Int in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, floating-point

I want to have the integer value of the following floating point value:

```
var floatingPointValue = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000
```

I don't care if the integer value of this floating point number is actually an integer or a string.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`Int64` is large enough to hold a time interval of some million
years measured in milliseconds:

```
let milliSeconds = Int64(someDate.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
let milliSecondsString = String(milliSeconds)
```

Answer (score 1):

Int64 is enough to hold the value you needed

```
let floatingPointValue = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000
let intValue = Int64(floatingPointValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

The crucial part is to use `Int64` instead of `Int` on 32-bit platforms. It will allow you to use 8 bytes of memory (from −9223372036854775808 to +9223372036854775807)

```
Int64(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
```